# Imagick extension installation issue xampp

Tags: imagick, php-8

I am trying to install Imagick extension on windows 10 with PHP version 8.0.3 but getting below error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'php_imagick.dll' (tried: D:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll (The
> specified module could not be found),
> D:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_imagick.dll.dll (The specified module could
> not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

```
Windows : 10 X64 
PHP version : 8.0.3
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. I have added imagick.dll file in xampp\php\ext directory
2. Added CORE_RL_*.dll and IM_MOD_RL_*.dll in xampp\php folder.
3. Added extension=php_imagick.dll in xampp\php\php.ini file
4. Restarted xammp
5. Getting below error on webpage
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNmCY.png)
6. In the PHP error log below error is logged.
   PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imagick.dll'

Comment: Seems pretty obvious.

Comment: If you have any thoughts/suggestions to solve the issue. Please share. I am stuck with this issue

Comment: What exactly have you done to install it?

Comment: 1. Added php_imagick.dll file to the ext directory 
2. Extract from ImageMagick-….zip files and directory and save them to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe), or to a directory in your PATH variable
3. Added this line to your php.ini file: extension=php_imagick.dll
4 .Restart the Apache/NGINX Windows service (if applicable)

Comment: https://github.com/mentax/Imagick_for_php8

Comment: @Chaitali Please click the [edit] link under the question, and include the steps **you actually did**, not just the guidance you were trying to follow. Where did **you** find "the ext directory" for step 1? Which directory did **you** put the files in at step 2? Did you decide that step 4 was applicable? Also, have you read the error message, and looked whether the paths it mentions matches the paths you put the files in?

Comment: @IMSoP I have added steps as you said. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First download this: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.7.0/php_imagick-3.7.0-8.0-ts-vs16-x64.zip

1. Extract from `php_imagick-….zip` the `php_imagick.dll file`, and save it to the `ext` directory of your PHP installation
2. Extract from php_imagick-….zip all the other DLL files and save them to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe)
3. Add this line to your `php.ini` file:
   `extension=php_imagick.dll`
4. Restart the Apache/NGINX Windows service (if applicable)